# reveal.js iframe embed video fullscreen issue firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, embed, reveal.js

I used reveal.js for our Bandpage. In the chapter Media, there are embed Youtube videos. My Problem is: When clicking on the fullscreen button, only the background image appears, not the video. Problem appears with firefox, It works in internet explorer. How can I fix this?
Thanks a lot!

The Page is: http://www.circus-rhapsody.de/

And the code looks like this:

```
<section data-background=bg/3.jpg>
     <section id="Media">
     <h1>Media</h1>
     </section>

     <section id="vid0">
     <h2>Musikvideo</h2>
     <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/9eFL_S6XmG8?rel=0"
     allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="480"
     width="853"></iframe>
     </section></section>
```